# API server relays Kerberos authentication by SPNEGO

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

I want Kerberos authentication with SPNEGO from Chrome on Windows PC to Hadoop(kerberized).

In the case of requesting Hadoop directly from a windows PC as below, I think that authentication will pass normally.

```
|Windows PC(Chrome)| -- SPNEGO --> |Hadoop(HDFS..etc)|
```

However, in the actual system configuration, there is a REST API in the meantime and it is necessary to relay requests to Hadoop.

```
|Windows PC(Chrome)| -- SPNEGO --> |REST API Server| --> SPNEGO --> |Hadoop(HDFS..etc)|
```

Is this possible?

If so, what kind of implementation is required on the REST API side in order to pass the Windows PC credentials intact to Hadoop?

Comment: "Double hop" is usually forbidden for security reasons : if an attacker takes control of your API server then it can impersonate any connected user on any server/service anywhere. Duh.

Comment: Microsoft has "constrained delegation" to mitigate the risks, hence with a .NET service and lots of patience you may get a security clearance...

Comment: Hi. I just knew that "constrained delegation" is necessary in this configuration. Thanks!